# Tag is overflowing into other elements on the website

Tags: html, css, navigation, overflow

My `h1` tag is supposed to be **similar to a banner a box shown on the webpage**, but instead the color background is overflowing into my navigation above. I also have a problem with my graphics alignment. That problem seems easy enough so I will try and fix that myself while I wait for an answer. I may have found a troubleshoot for the banner by combining the content of the tags but I would like to find a way to have it like I did before. I would be glad to supply CSS and/or html to any part of the website. If it's any help I am using Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2018 in Google Chrome browser. Thanks for your help.

code

```css
body {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: Georgia, Arial, serif;
  color: #DD847F;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #F7E0C4;
  border-color: #B00F32;
  border-width: 10px;
  border-style: double;
  margin: 100px 200px;
  padding: 0px 0px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2.8em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #F7E0C4;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, serif;
  border-left: 100px solid #B00F32;
  border-right: 100px solid #B00F32;
  border-bottom: 100px solid #B00F32;
  border-top: 100px solid #B00F32;
  background-color: #B00F32;
  padding-top: 0px;
}

div.info {
  text-size: 40%;
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<h1>Web Portfolio</h1>
<div id="skipnav">
  <a href="#main">Skip to Main Content</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please, provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: @Adam What code would you like me to supply? It's just basic, I provided my CSS for h1, list and navigation. Is there any specific HTML places you need?

Comment: @raul.vila I provided the CSS linked with the problem, I also provided the HTML on my Index page. If you need HTML for the other pages just let me know.

Comment: The code where you're having this problem! every post should be included with minimal code to help us figure out where the problem is.

Comment: @Adam I have provided that code above. The only effected places are h1 and navigation. That code is right above the CSS and below the paragraph about my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do? or similar to it?

open this code in full page *Expand snippet*

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: Georgia, Arial, serif;
  color: #DD847F;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #F7E0C4;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100wh;
  position: relative;
}

.main--title {
  border: 10px double #B00F32;
  line-height: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 15px 25px;
}

.skip--content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -10%);
}
```

```html
<h1 class="main--title">Web Portfolio</h1>
<div id="skipnav" class="skip--content">
  <a href="#main">Skip to Main Content</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any already created CSS that I need to replace or just exempt all together?

Comment: You can adjust or add more styles! but is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: I tried it out on a decoy javascript page and it doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for. I might have missed something so I will still experiment with this and hopefully it works out. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Update- I've been experimenting with it for a while now and it doesn't seem to be fixing the problem but still, thank you for your help!

Comment: what is the problem?